# Create a directory using Perl Script in docker

Tags: docker, perl

I have a simple Perl script as below, which creates a directory `logs` under `/ops/dim/foo`. This Perl script does not create the directory when running in a Docker container.

makedir-script.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use warnings;
use strict;

my @i = (1..9);

for(@i){
    print("$_: Hello, World!\n");
}
my $sptpath = "/ops/dim/foo";
mkdir "$sptpath/logs" unless(-d "$sptpath/logs");
print("Opening POD created logs folder!\n");
```

docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.10
WORKDIR /ops/dim/foo
COPY makedir-script.pl ./
CMD  perl makedir-script.pl
```

Comment: You didn't try your own script because it doesn't define the $scriptpath variable and the strict mode is on. Pay attention to the errors you get when running that script.

Comment: printing mistake, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Your script fails because `$scriptpath` isn't set to anything.

It tries to do `mkdir "$scriptpath/logs"` because `/ops/dim/foo/logs` doesn't exist.

You probably want to use `$sptpath` instead, so your statement becomes

```
mkdir "$sptpath/logs" unless(-d "$sptpath/logs");
```

Comment: You are correct, however i had put the wrong script.

Answer (score 1):

@Hans Kilian answer is fine, but if you only need to create a folder, is easy to do in your Dockerfile. Just like this:

```
RUN mkdir -p /ops/dim/foo/logs
```